# Phase difference of a periodic wave

Tags: waves

Can the value of a phase difference be more than 360°? For example, if I want to calculate the phase difference between a point on a wave cycle and another point of another wave cycle.
Do I need to subtract 360° repetitively from the phase difference until i get a phase difference less than 360° or can the value of a phase difference be more than 360°?

Comment: Can a circle can have more than 360 degrees? I don’t think the question is clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not talking about a single wave cycle but multiple waves of cycle for this question.

Comment: Are you asking about a constant or a time varying phase relationship?

Answer (score 1):

The phase difference can be greater than 360, but those values represent exactly the same phase shift as a value between zero and 360.  Another way to look at it is to recognize that there are many numbers (an infinite number, in fact) that point to the same phase shift.  There's nothing wrong with using those values.  A calculator will calculate the trig functions just fine.  It's just unconventional, and it looks odd.

Comment: And perhaps it should be stressed that all phase shift values differing by 360 degrees have the same *physical* meaning.

Comment: Although if the angle's too high, you get errors due to the finite precision of floating-point numbers. Here's a [live Python demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNzDEOwyAQRNGeU_wSsCXHSpTCUg5DETtbsKANBccPosp0Txr900omp_ZBci3WqLLyFXWJFzsbT3cWQxDFkl5vv6_cb-FwjOk4PYgRmeyDykKaqiba_Mhp-HOfeV-FSA_hB98EIZw=&lang=python)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at a single point on a wave, and measuring the phase difference of another wave, relative to that same point, then yes, the phase difference can be greater than $360^o$, if the first wave has passed the second by more than a full wavelength.

> Do I need to subtract 360° repetitively from the phase difference until i get a phase difference less than 360° or can the value of a phase difference be more than 360°?

A phase difference of
$\Delta \phi = 360^o$ is equivalent to a phase difference $\Delta \phi = 0$. Seems like using numbers greater than $360^o$ might be tedious.